# struct forward declaration and intrusive pointer

Tags: visual-c++, c++

Сделал вот такой абстрактный класс, который должен наследовать любой класс с подсчетом ссылок :

```
    template<class T>
    class ReferenceCounter
    {
    public:

        ReferenceCounter();
        ~ReferenceCounter();

        void addRef();
        void release();

        uint32 getCountReferences() const;

    protected:
        int32* pCountReferences;

        virtual void destroyObject() = 0;
        virtual void shallowCopy(const T& rhs) = 0;
    };

    template<class T>
    inline ReferenceCounter<T>::ReferenceCounter() 
    {
        pCountReferences = new int32;
        *pCountReferences = 1;
    }

    template<class T>
    inline ReferenceCounter<T>::~ReferenceCounter() 
    {
        if(pCountReferences != NULL && *pCountReferences == 0)
        {
            delete pCountReferences;
            pCountReferences = NULL;
        }
    }

    template<class T>
    inline void ReferenceCounter<T>::addRef()
    {
        debug_assert((*pCountReferences) >= 0, "Incorrect value of count references");
        ++(*pCountReferences);
    }

    template<class T>
    inline void ReferenceCounter<T>::release()
    {
        debug_assert((*pCountReferences) > 0, "Incorrect value of count references");
        (*pCountReferences)--;

        if(pCountReferences != NULL && *pCountReferences == 0)
        {
            destroyObject();
        }
    }

    template<class T>
    inline uint32 ReferenceCounter<T>::getCountReferences() const
    {
        return *pCountReferences;
    }
```

Вот класс умного указателя :

```
    template<class T>
    class SmartPtr
    {
    public:
        SmartPtr();
        SmartPtr(T* pInst);
        SmartPtr(const SmartPtr<T>& rhs);
        ~SmartPtr();

        void operator = (const SmartPtr<T>& rhs);
        T* operator -> () const;
        T* getData() const;

        bool isNULL() const;

    private:
        T* pInst;
    };

    template<class T>
    SmartPtr<T>::SmartPtr() : pInst(NULL) {}

    template<class T>
    SmartPtr<T>::SmartPtr(T* pInst) : pInst(pInst) {}

    template<class T>
    SmartPtr<T>::~SmartPtr() 
    {
        if(pInst != NULL)
        {
            pInst->release();
        }
    }

    template<class T>
    SmartPtr<T>::SmartPtr(const SmartPtr<T>& rhs)
    {
        this->pInst = rhs.pInst;
        if(pInst != NULL)
        {
            pInst->addRef();
        }
    }

    template<class T>
    void SmartPtr<T>::operator= (const SmartPtr<T>& rhs)
    {
        this->pInst = rhs.pInst;
        if(pInst != NULL)
        {
            pInst->addRef();
        }
    }

    template<class T>
    T* SmartPtr<T>::operator->() const
    {
        return pInst;
    }

    template<class T>
    T* SmartPtr<T>::getData() const
    {
        return pInst;
    }

    template<class T>
    bool SmartPtr<T>::isNULL() const
    {
        return pInst == NULL;
    }
```

Код где тестировал это :

```
#include <iostream>
#include "ReferenceCounter.h"
#include "SmartPtr.h"

using namespace std;
using namespace OGE::memory;

class B;

class A : public ReferenceCounter<A>
{
public:
    A();
    A(const A& rhs);
    ~A();

    SmartPtr<B> getB();
    void operator = (const A& rhs);

private:
    void destroyObject();
    void shallowCopy(const A& rhs);
};

class B : public ReferenceCounter<B>
{
private:
    void destroyObject() {} ;
    void shallowCopy(const B& rhs) {};
};

A::A()
{
    cout << "Create object" << endl;
}

A::A(const A& rhs)
{
    shallowCopy(rhs);
    addRef();
    cout << "copy constructor " << endl;
}

A::~A()
{
    release();
}

void A::destroyObject()
{
    cout << "destroy" << endl;
}

void A::shallowCopy(const A& rhs)
{
    this->pCountReferences = rhs.pCountReferences;
}

void A::operator = (const A& rhs)
{
    shallowCopy(rhs);
    addRef();
    cout << "operator = " << endl;
}

SmartPtr<B> A::getB()
{
    return SmartPtr<B>(new B());
}

SmartPtr<A> getA()
{
    SmartPtr<A> a(new A());
    return a;
}

int main()
{
    getA();
    return 0;
}
```

Это код отлично работает, все разрушается. 
А вот тут, где используется struct forward declaration не вызывается конструктор копировщик из-за чего о корректности нельзя говорить.

```
int main()
{
   A a;
   a.getB();
}
```

Помогите разобраться в чем проблема ?

Answer (score 1):

Думаю Вам стоит изучить сначала как сделаны имеющиеся хорошие варианты - boost::shared_ptr<T>, std::shared_ptr<T>, CComPtr<T> - и тогда все вопросы отпадут (если уж их использовать совсем никак нельзя и надо писать что-то свое).

Comment: Проблема была вот тут : 
SmartPtr<B> A::getB()
{
    return SmartPtr<B>(new B());
}

Вот такой код заработал :
SmartPtr<B> A::getB()
{
    SmartPtr<B> b(new B());
    return b;
}

Видимо проблема была в RVO ?

Comment: Да, скорее всего RVO.